# Why reference type is not assigned a value when I pass it as parameter?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, reference

Here, `Person` is a class, hence a reference type, it should be changed when I pass it as parameter in another function and assign it there.

Why `program.person` is null here after call to `ChangePerson` ?

```
namespace IndirectlyPropertySet
{
    class Program
    {
        public Person _person;

        public Person person
        {
            get { return _person; }
            set
            {
                if (_person != value)
                {
                    _person = value;
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program = new Program();

            ChangePerson(program.person); 
            // Why program.person is null after executing this ?

            program.person = new Person() { Name = "b", Age = 2 };
        }

        static void ChangePerson(Person p)
        {
            Person pe = new Person() { Name = "a", Age = 1 };
            p = pe;
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you setting program.person before passing it? you need to write program.person = new Person() { Name = "b", Age = 2 }; before calling changeperson() and morevoer i am not sure what you are trying to get as output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an addition to @JonSkeet's answer, if you rewrote your code to do this instead it would work.

```
static void ChangePerson(ref Person p)
{
    Person pe = new Person() { Name = "a", Age = 1 };
    p = pe;
}

void Main()
{
    Person p = program.person;
    ChangePerson(ref p);
    // program.person will now be set to "a" with age 1 at this point
    program.person = p;   

    program.person = new Person() { Name = "b", Age = 2 };
}
```

The key point is to pass the reference type *by reference* i.e. adding the `ref` keyword to your parameter.

Answer (score 3):

> Why program.person is null here after call to ChangePerson ?

The argument (which is a reference) is being passed by value. When you change the value of the *parameter* to refer to a different object, that doesn't change the argument at all. Note that in this case you're not even passing a variable's value - you're passing the result of evaluating a (badly-named) property.

It's very important to understand the difference between:

- A variable
- A reference (e.g. the *value* of a variable)
- An object (which a reference value *refers to*)

Please read my [article on parameter passing on C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more information.